# How to parse information element in 802.11 probe request frame with gopacket

Tags: go, wifi, gopacket

Gopacket supports parsing information elements in beacon and probe response frames, like this:

```
for _, layer := range packet.Layers() {
    if layer.LayerType() == layers.LayerTypeDot11InformationElement {
        dot11info, ok := layer.(*layers.Dot11InformationElement)
        }
}
```

But gopacket doesn't support parsing information elements in probe request frame.
I can only use `packet.Layer(layers.LayerTypeDot11MgmtProbeReq).(*layers.Dot11MgmtProbeReq)`
to get the Contents and Payload, and the information elements are in this Contents.

So how can I parse these information elements in probe request frame?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you have to write yourself. Have you already tried [this](https://github.com/urld/wifitracker/blob/master/sniffer/sniffer.go) implementation?

The parser is the following:

```
func (pr *capturedRequest) decodeProbeRequestLayer(probeLayer *layers.Dot11MgmtProbeReq) {
    var body []byte
    body = probeLayer.LayerContents()
    for i := uint64(0); i < uint64(len(body)); {
        id := layers.Dot11InformationElementID(body[i])
        i++
        switch id {
        case layers.Dot11InformationElementIDSSID:
            elemLen := uint64(body[i])
            i++
            if elemLen > 0 {
                pr.SSID = string(body[i : i+elemLen])
                i += elemLen
            }
            break
        case layers.Dot11InformationElementIDVendor:
            pr.VendorSpecific = body[i+1:]
            return
        default:
            elemLen := uint64(body[i])
            i += 1 + elemLen
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As a head's up, the reason that you can't just parse IEs from probe requests like you could from beacons or probe responses is because gopacket itself never actually assigns to the `Payload` field of the `Dot11MgmtProbeReq` struct.  See `DecodeFromBytes` in [Dot11MgmtBeacon](https://github.com/google/gopacket/blob/master/layers/dot11.go#L1897) and [Dot11MgmtProbeResp](https://github.com/google/gopacket/blob/master/layers/dot11.go#L1834); [Dot11MgmtProbeReq](https://github.com/google/gopacket/blob/master/layers/dot11.go#L1819) has no such method.  Replacing `Dot11MgmtProbeReq` from gopacket with the following code fixes this issue (although this may be overkill for you):

```
type Dot11MgmtProbeReq struct {
    Dot11Mgmt
}

func decodeDot11MgmtProbeReq(data []byte, p gopacket.PacketBuilder) error {
    d := &Dot11MgmtProbeReq{}
    return decodingLayerDecoder(d, data, p)
}

func (m *Dot11MgmtProbeReq) LayerType() gopacket.LayerType  { return LayerTypeDot11MgmtProbeReq }
func (m *Dot11MgmtProbeReq) CanDecode() gopacket.LayerClass { return LayerTypeDot11MgmtProbeReq }
func (m *Dot11MgmtProbeReq) NextLayerType() gopacket.LayerType {
    return LayerTypeDot11InformationElement
}
func (m *Dot11MgmtProbeReq) DecodeFromBytes(data []byte, df gopacket.DecodeFeedback) error {
    m.Payload = data
    return m.Dot11Mgmt.DecodeFromBytes(data, df)
}
```

One straightforward way to extract IEs in general is to set up a single core function to pass the list of IEs from the current frame into a function that decodes all relevant elements into a `map[string][]byte` where the string is a human-readable name for the string.  That way, any frame-specific fields can be requested in their specific cases.  (You need to write a map[layers.Dot11InformationElementID]string` to do this).